# Security game for factoring

Tags: provable-security, factoring

this is probably a fairly simple request, but I have'nt been able to find it anywhere.

A lot of cryptography schemes have security games associated with them. In the [Book by Katz](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Emfy/moderncrypto/reading%20materials/Introduction_to_Modern_Cryptography.pdf), a bunch of schemes have a security game involved with them. This usually involves an Adversary trying to break the scheme, and a Challenger on the other side.

I was wondering what a security game for factoring would look like?
I really find the games very pedagogical, in making me understand the gist of different problem.

Comment: I'm not sure there would be such a thing, since factoring is just a computational problem, rather than a cryptographic protocol of some kind. Security games typically involve some interaction between the Adversary and the Challenger, but for factoring the Challenger would just send an integer N, and the Adversary must factor it without any other input. It's a bit boring from this perspective.